# Solr filter query for long type

Tags: solr

I have a long type field (TrieLongField) date_tri in Solr 6 to stock date with the format YYYYMMDD, ex: 20180311
I want to get all documents for recent 3 months, here is the request:
http://test:8983/solr/valid/select?facet.field=date_tri&q=*:*&facet=on&fq=sub%28date_tri,20180311%29<300&indent=on

fq: sub(date_tri,20180311)<300

But there are a lot documents older than 3 months in the result list, how to correct it?

Comment: Have you tried included the query in your `fl` as well? My guess is that since TrieFields generate multiple values with the default precision step (for range searches), the `sub` function is picking the wrong one. You could try using the PointLongField instead.